# Type error when using Logical or with Typescript 4

Tags: typescript, typescript4.0

I have a class property that is constructed with an initial value:

```js
private _httpClient: ClientInterface = new HttpURLConnectionClient();
```

which I want to override if it's passed when instantiating the class:

```js
class Class {
  private _httpClient: ClientInterface = new HttpURLConnectionClient();

  constructor(httpClient?: ClientInterface) {
    if (httpClient) {
      this._httpClient = httpClient // replaces existing _httpClient
    }
  }
}

new Class(httpClient)
```

I'm migrating this code to TypeScript 4, and I assumed the following would be equivalent:

```js
class Class {
  private _httpClient: ClientInterface = new HttpURLConnectionClient();

  constructor(httpClient?: ClientInterface) {
      this._httpClient ||= httpClient // Shows ts error! But should be equivalent to this._httpClient = httpClient || this._httpClient
  }
}

new Class(httpClient)
```

but it displays `Type 'X | undefined' is not assignable to Type 'X'`, which is understandable if I was not using the logical or.

I know I can solve this issue if I do this, but I want to understand why the solution above shows a type error:

```js
class Class {
  private _httpClient: ClientInterface;

  constructor(httpClient?: ClientInterface) {
      this._httpClient = httpClient || new HttpURLConnectionClient()
  }
}

new Class(httpClient)
```

Comment: I don't see an error in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBtgXASXNeJZAbwF8AoBdOAZxuQAkwwAHAVQCUAZVAexBAQEYYPwxZwyYAFsW6CNOxh64pXkixEKMuUrU6affWLlkyFlGAA3OJGQB9ABbMWq8AC5DEsOoJbkALzIggDujC6cPPyCwqIgbmAAFACUANy6Zgj8NGBQAK7CvFCJzqwJAPyeCb6aSMkkpmZSMMglLgn1Jk1NYI7ANAB0Tu2YSoHIpa6jkgD0M8hQEHJa9BAAHv0iIADmDpMJjWYUR+SkQA), as I'd expect `if (httpClient)` narrows from `ClientInterface | undefined` to `ClientInterface`.

Comment: I guess you missed the entire question. This part of the code is fine. I want to replace it with the one below, using logical or `||=` which throws: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoaXoAcCuARiAJbDRKIoC80A5AGYD2jtA3OptsIwHbIBOeYEkb8AFGH4BzAAwB+AFzQBxHlICUaTtmxIAFsQgA6CsmgAfczUmzt0AL7pH6bnxSnq0HvADucSmLqLrwQjCDwRiCMUmIARB4AtB5KsQA05JQmlEFYQA

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, sorry - note `||=` deals with the *left-hand side* possibly being undefined, not the right-hand side. It's `a = a || b` not `a = b || a`.

Comment: You can simplify all this to `constructor(private _httpClient: ClientInterface = new HttpURLConnectionClient())` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBtgXASXNeJZAbwF8AoBdOAZxuQAkwwAHAVQCUAZVAexBAQEYYPwxZwJCpWp00s+sXLJkCfjTBQArsN5QAFCyjAAbnEjIA+gAtmLcdjAAueRLB5IsRCgC8yQQDujHacPPyCwqIgDuD6AJRxJMrIFKRAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have slightly misinterpreted what [short-circuiting assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#short-circuiting-assignment-operators) is doing. `a ||= b` is equivalent to `a = a || b`, it deals with the *left-hand side* of the assignment possibly being undefined, not the right-hand side.

In your case, that's something like:

```js
this._httpClient = this._httpClient || httpClient
```

*(The compiler actually emits `this._httpClient || (this._httpClient = httpClient)`, but it's easier to think about this way.)*

Your latter version is the other way around (`a = b || a`):

```js
this._httpClient = httpClient || new HttpURLConnectionClient()
                              // ^ equivalent to this._httpClient
```

Probably the easiest way to implement this would be to use a [parameter property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) with a default value:

```js
class Class {
  constructor(private _httpClient: ClientInterface = new HttpURLConnectionClient()) { }
}
```